# Не корректное выполнение примера из книги "Python в системном администрировании UNIX и Linux"

Tags: python, unix

Здравствуйте. 
В книге есть пример:

```
for i in range(10):
    !date > ${i}.txt
```

Который должен показывать взаимодействие ipython с bash, и создавать 10 текстовых файлов с датой, однако у меня создаётся только один файл с именем sh.txt. Что я делаю не так? Версия python 2.7.3, ipython - 0.13.1 
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Возможно, всё же есть различие между вашим кодом и кодом в книге?

Comment: Уже пробовал копипастить, результат тот же.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Точно связано с версией IPython.
Начиная с версии 0.10 данный пример не работает (в книге использовалась версия 0.8.4), в случае если возле `{i}` указан символ доллара:

```
for i in range(10):
    !date > ${i}.txt
```

Но без него - действительно получается нужный результат.

В release note не было найдено пояснения этого изменения, возможно, оно связано с чем-то другим.

Answer (score 1):

работает вот так (без знака `$`):

```
for i in range(10):
  !date > {i}.txt
```

с чем связано такое расхождение между книгой (возможно, слегка устаревшей) и «реальной жизнью» — не знаю.